# Is there an alternative to B2.SPICE A/D for Mac OS X?

Tags: simulation, spice, tools

I've tried B2.SPICE A/D on Windows and I liked it. Is there an easy-to-use application like B2.SPICE A/D that uses SPICE and allows **drawing** the schematic of the circuit and simulating it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LTspice on a Mac. I use it, it is free, the schematic editor is good once you get used to its slightly quirky operation. The simulator seems good.

Comment: I am learning how to use it currently but I think B2.SPICE is easier to use. Can you refer to some good basic tutorials?

Comment: Look at www.linear.com Also look up Simon Bramble, and search LTspice on YouTube

Comment: There are many examples included with the tool that you can play with, but they are hard to find. Right-click on the LTSpice.app application, select "Show Package Contents", then navigate to "Contents -> examples -> Educational".